# How to define tablespace when creating CTXCAT index

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

Is it possible to define the tablespace in the index creation?
If so what is the syntax? I can't find any reference.

I try something like:

`CREATE INDEX "X_INDEX" ON "X_TABLE" ("X_COLUMN") TABLESPACE X_3 INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CTXCAT"`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike regular indexes, which only have 1 segment, Domain indexes create a number of different tables and indexes, each of which can be in a different tablespace. So [you need to specify tablespace settings in the BASIC_STORAGE preference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cdatadic.htm#sthref834).

Here's an example based on that link.

```
begin
ctx_ddl.create_preference('mystore', 'BASIC_STORAGE');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'I_TABLE_CLAUSE',
                        'tablespace foo storage (initial 1K)'); 
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'K_TABLE_CLAUSE',
                        'tablespace foo storage (initial 1K)'); 
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'R_TABLE_CLAUSE',
                        'tablespace users storage (initial 1K) lob
                         (data) store as (disable storage in row cache)');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'N_TABLE_CLAUSE',
                        'tablespace foo storage (initial 1K)'); 
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'I_INDEX_CLAUSE',
                        'tablespace foo storage (initial 1K) compress 2');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('mystore', 'P_TABLE_CLAUSE',
                        'tablespace foo storage (initial 1K)'); 
end;
/

CREATE INDEX "X_INDEX" ON "X_TABLE" ("X_COLUMN") 
    INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CTXCAT" PARAMETERS(STORAGE mystore);
```